# Why can't get second parameter value from url.action

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

Html script code for send parameter to query in controller and send back to create Google chart.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: '@Url.Action("FromToResults", "Chart", new { From = @ViewBag.SelectFrom, To = @ViewBag.SelectTo })',
            success: function (result) {
                google.charts.load('current', {
                    'packages': ['corechart']
                });
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                    drawChart(result);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I set 2 Parameter(From , To) send to FromToResults class in controller(below)

```
public ActionResult FromToResults(DateTime From, DateTime To)
    {
        return Json(FromToResult(From , To), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

After debug I only get From value but can't get To value.

Comment: Why are you using contentType as "application/json" if you are actually just extracting the parameters from the query ?

Also why are you using a post and not a  "GET"

Comment: I not sure in JSON but In this point i don't know why i just get 1 parameter and how to solve.

Comment: syntax of url.action is wrong or this script will add other option for send 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use a GET and extract the From and To from the query strings

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("FromToResults", "Chart", new { From = @ViewBag.SelectFrom, To = @ViewBag.SelectTo })',
            success: function (result) {
                google.charts.load('current', {
                    'packages': ['corechart']
                });
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                    drawChart(result);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```